# How to expand the all values from group by query?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the rows from the group by count's. My scenario is pid should count should 5 but the value of pid whatever.

```
select pid,count(*) from similar where pattern_len=5 group by id limit 5;
```

This will give the following result

```
| 1a4m_D |        4 |
| 1a4o_A |        2 |
| 1a4o_B |        2 |
| 1a4o_C |        2 |
| 1a4o_D |        2 |
```

Now I am trying to get the all  rows which is matching with those condition, so for my above query it will give the 12 rows (4+2+2+2+2).(I am trying to get the all colums) I am trying with different queries but I am not getting any result. How can I solve this?

Sample input

```
+--------+-------------+---------+----------------------------+-------------+----------------------------+
| pid     | pattern_len | pattern | pattern_range              | range_count | position                   |
+--------+-------------+---------+----------------------------+-------------+----------------------------+
| 1a4m_D |           5 | aaaaa   | [7 to 11] [8 to 12]        |           2 | [7 to 11] [8 to 12]        |
| 1a4m_D |           5 | aaaaa   | [5 to 9] [6 to 10]         |           2 | [5 to 9] [6 to 10]         |
| 1a4o_B |           5 | aaaaa   | [122 to 126] [123 to 127]  |           2 | [122 to 126] [123 to 127]  |
| 1a4o_B |           5 | aaaaa   | [26 to 30] [226 to 230]    |           2 | [26 to 30] [226 to 230]    |
| 1a4o_B |           5 | aaaaa   | [3 to 7] [4 to 8]          |           2 | [3 to 7] [4 to 8]          |
+--------+-------------+---------+----------------------------+-------------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this query should do it 
`select * from similar where pattern_len=5`

Comment: No, I need the unique count of 5 ids.

Comment: You have shown us an incorrect output.  Please also show sample data and the expected output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This is the sample output. Actually I am trying  to get all the rows of those 5 pids those pattern length is 5.

Comment: I see sample input but no sample output. If the input is as described what do you want the output to look like?

Comment: `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` makes little sense.

Comment: Please make a [DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) with your sample data

Comment: Incidentally, the likelihood of ever wanting to group by something other than what appears in the SELECT is virtually nil.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which MySQL version, but you can do it in MySQL 8.x.

First, you'll need to add an `ORDER BY` for your `LIMIT` to make sense. Then, this query should expand the subselection:

```
with
y as (
  select pid 
  from similar 
  where pattern_len = 5
  group by pid
  order by count(*) desc
  limit 5
)
select * 
from similar
where pid in (select pid from y)
```